# Best way to get first single value of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the fastest and best way to get first value from list?
There are multiple techniques, but what is the best (memory and speed) and why?

Examples below. I would be grateful for other techniques as well:

```py
listis = [1, 2, 3, 4]

### 1:
###----------

value = next(iter(listis))

print(value)

### 2:
###----------

value = listis[0]

print(value)

### 3:
###----------

value, *args = listis

print(value)
```

Comment: Anything other than `listis[0]` would be a baffling choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`value = listis[0]` is going to be unbeatable here as it’s just creating a new name (`value`) referencing `listis[0]`.

More importantly, it’s obvious what you actually mean. That makes life much better for the next person who looks at your code, who will likely be you.

Try:

```
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit("value = next(iter(listis))", setup="listis = [1, 2, 3, 4]", number=1_000_000))
print(timeit.timeit("value = listis[0]", setup="listis = [1, 2, 3, 4]", number=1_000_000))
print(timeit.timeit("value, *args = listis", setup="listis = [1, 2, 3, 4]", number=1_000_000))
```

This will show you that `value = listis[0]` is the fastest.

```
0.0976
0.0264
0.1190
```

Answer (score 4):

Calling the list element by its element number is always the fastest way. You aren't doing any calculation nor using any functions to get to it.

```
print(listis[0])
```

Comment: To back this up, a simple `timeit` of each of these 3 approaches puts the other options around 4-5x slower.

Answer (score 2):

We can compare these 3 ways:

Here the script:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from time import time


def nrml(lst):
    value = lst[0]


def it(lst):
    value = next(iter(lst))


def arg(lst):
    value, *args = lst


def test():
    res = []
    for i in range(100, 100000, 100):
        the_lst = [0] * i
        nrml_s = time()
        nrml(the_lst)
        nrml_e = time()

        it_s = time()
        it(the_lst)
        it_e = time()

        arg_s = time()
        arg(the_lst)
        arg_e = time()

        res.append(
            [
                i,
                nrml_e - nrml_s,
                it_e - it_s,
                arg_e - arg_s
            ]
        )

    res = np.array(res)

    plt.plot(res[:, 0], res[:, 1], label="Indexing")
    plt.plot(res[:, 0], res[:, 2], label="Iter")
    plt.plot(res[:, 0], res[:, 3], label="Unpack")

    plt.legend()

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Please notice we did not check the memory usage. Just the time.

Here the result:

[image: Getting first element of list]

Please notice the `Iter` and the `Indexing` are close.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. I'm sure nobody will ever use unpacking for lists after seeing this.

Answer (score 1):

```
listis[0]
```

This is the best choice in every case.

Python `list`s were created to make their elements accessable by `[i]` syntax.

---

For example this code...

```
listis[-1]
```

...will return the last element.

---

This code...

```
listis[::-1]
```

...will reverse the list

---

This code...

```
listis[2:]
```

...will return the list without the first two elements.